# How to configure Receiver batch size for Azure Functions EventHub listener?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobssdk, azure-functions

In the latest [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/2.0.0-beta2), it gives you the ability to [receive batches of messages](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support#receiving-events) from eventhubs. I would like to set how many messages I want to receive in a batch.

The core ServiceBus library allows you to overload the `Receive()` function and provide the [batch size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubreceiver#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubReceiver_Receive_System_Int32_).

How does one do this in the [initial config of an EventHubs receiver](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support#configuration), or is something else required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in Functions via the `eventHub` configuration block in `host.json` as described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json). E.g.:

```
{
    "eventHub": {
        "maxBatchSize": 500,
        "prefetchCount": 100
    }
}
```

We apply those configuration settings to the `EventProcessorOptions` when we create the `EventProcessorHost` (see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script/Binding/ServiceBusScriptBindingProvider.cs#L70)).

Answer (score 2):

Steph,

The `MaxBatchSize` can be configured through [EventProcessorOptions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor/EventProcessorOptions.cs), you can pass it as a parameter when creating a new [EventHubConfiguration](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/EventHubs/EventHubConfiguration.cs).

```
var options = EventProcessorOptions.DefaultOptions;
options.MaxBatchSize = 50;
var eventHubConfig = new EventHubConfiguration(options);
string eventHubName = "MyHubName";
eventHubConfig.AddSender(eventHubName, "Endpoint=sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=SendRule;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxx");
eventHubConfig.AddReceiver(eventHubName, "Endpoint=sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=ReceiveRule;SharedAccessKey=yyyyyyy");

config.UseEventHub(eventHubConfig);
JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
```

As you can notice in the source code of [EventHubConfiguration.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/EventHubs/EventHubConfiguration.cs) if no `EventProcessorOptions` is specified, the `MaxBatchSize` is set to `1000` instead of `10` by default.

```
public EventHubConfiguration(
        EventProcessorOptions options, 
        PartitionManagerOptions partitionOptions = null)
{
    if (options == null)
    {
        options = EventProcessorOptions.DefaultOptions;
        options.MaxBatchSize = 1000;
     }
     _partitionOptions = partitionOptions;

     _options = options;
}
```